# super.a = b instead of super(b)

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends, super

I'm learning the super keyword and accidentally get this, here's an example :

```
    public class A {
       double a;
       public A (double a) {
          this.a = a;
       }
    }
    public class B extends A {
       public B (double b) {
          super.a = b;  //***
       }
    }
```

The usual way to do this as in the tutorials is `super(b)` to reusing its parent constructor, but what is wrong with `super.a = b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write your class A like this:

```
public class A {
    double a;
    public A(double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

you overwrite the default constructor and in the line `this.a = a` you are accessing instance variable and setting the values and in class B:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(double b) {
        super.a = b; // ***
    }
}
```

you are trying to access instance variables of Class B through the constructor because `super.a` in here , the super referes to the constructor and its wrong and throwing the `Implicit super constructor A() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor` which means: in Class `B` its looking for a constructor which has no parameter because you overwrite the default constructor of class and it can't recognize it by calling `super.a = b` so you have to call the super constructor as a function and in the first line of code:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(double b) {
        super(b);
        super.a = b; // ***
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no "constructor inheritance" in Java. If the super class doesn't have a no-arg constructor, you must explicitly call its constructor (or one of them if there are several). If you don't, you'll get a compilation error.